# regex for matching and excluding the rest

Tags: regex

i want to match a very simple number-bar-number pattern : 1/2

My regex is:  `([0-9]{1}\/[0-9]{1})`

The problem is that I match things I want to exclude. I need exact matching excluding the rest.

My regex return as valid patterns as :

1/12344

2/23ABC

2/233423/2425

[update]

tested with some txt files using GREP, still having issues. By instance:

2/3/16   (it's a date and it matches the pattern, so grep returned the entire line)

I'm not very versed on regex so any help would be very much appreciated

Regards

Comment: So, to get this straight, you do not want `1/2344` to match, but it is matching? Also, with your current RegEx, you can replace `[0-9]` with `\d` and remove the `{1}` (typing it once is the same, so there is **never** any need to use `{1}`)

Comment: `/\b[0-9]\/[0-9]\b/` or `/\b\d\/\d\b/`

Comment: Yep, that's the issue. The matching pattern keeps getting a lot of undesired strings that, matched the rule, but I don't need.     Word boundaries!!!! that's the key.   Thanks a lot

Comment: Still having issues. Check this string:  2/1/16  it's a date and it's matched. Grep gives me the entire string if found, so something else is needed to exclude it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
(?:^|\s)(\d+\/\d+)(?=\s|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fZ2oZ7/1)

**Explanation:**
`(?: … )`: Non-capturing group [sample](https://regex101.com/r/bU9dN1/1)
`^`: Start of string or start of line depending on multiline mode [sample](https://regex101.com/r/jG7wZ9/1)
`|`: Alternation / OR operand [sample](https://regex101.com/r/uQ0iC0/1)
`\`: Escapes a special character [sample](https://regex101.com/r/aM5iM5/1)
`( … )`: Capturing group [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qL1pP8/1)
`+`: One or more [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wV7cV2/1)
`(?=…)`: Positive lookahead [sample](https://regex101.com/r/cV6wG7/1)
`$`: End of string or end of line depending on multiline mode [sample](https://regex101.com/r/eC5iY3/1)

Comment: Not at start of line or string, but applicable with a few changes. Thanks

Comment: @user1319342 i updated regex, hope this help.

Comment: Tim007, now it's perfect!   Thnaks